# How to set local storage for capacitors in ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic4, capacitor

I'm new to ionic, and i'm using capacitor. How to use local storage for capacitor to store the api token. there are many tutorial about cordova localstorage. But i don't know to do it for capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use **Ionic Storage**

Take a look to the [doc here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage). You don't need to do some special thing. It works independently of the platform.